# Get only personal record of the DB and not all of the records

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, authentication

When you log in on my site, you'll directly be directed to your profiles page. So that you can see your name, phone, email, etc. But at the moment when I log in on my site, I get directed to my profile page but I get all data for every user in my DB. So I'm getting the name of every user, the phone of every user, etc. I only want to get the data of the person who logged in. How can I achieve this?
I did some thinking about it, and came up with doing a `where userID = ID of the user HERE`
But I don't know where I'll be able to get the ID of this user. When logging in I'm starting a session, so would I need to store the logged in users ID in the session? Or isn't that secure?

I'm learning and working with CodeIgniter, so I'm doing it in a MVC pattern.

**Controller where I login and set my session**

```
if($query){
    $data = array(
             'username' => $this->input->post('loginEmail'),
             'is_logged_in' => true
            );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

**Controller**

```
if($logged_in){
    //if the user is logged in 
    $this->load->model('profile_model');

    if($query = $this->profile_model->userInfo()){
        $data['records'] = $query;
            $data['content'] = 'profile_view';
            $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Profile_model extends CI_Model{

    function userInfo(){
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**View where my I want to show my data**

```
if(isset($records)){
    foreach($records as $row){
        echo $row->username;
        echo $row->cellphone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are missing is a WHERE statement in your model. As an argument for the WHERE statement you can use your session variable containing your email address(assuming your database table stores emails in a field called 'username':

```
class Profile_model extends CI_Model{

    function userInfo(){

        $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));

        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');

    return $query->result();

    }

}
```

Or you can pass the email/username to the model from the controller:

```
if($logged_in){
    //if the user is logged in 
    $this->load->model('profile_model');
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    if($query = $this->profile_model->userInfo($username)){
        $data['records'] = $query;
            $data['content'] = 'profile_view';
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
    }
}
```

and then in your model:

```
class Profile_model extends CI_Model{

    function userInfo($username){

        $this->db->where('username', $username);

        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');

    return $query->result();

    }

}
```

I don't know what your columns are named in your database, or I could be more precise.

If usernames in the database are different from email addresses, change the line in the model to:

```
$this->db->where('email', $username);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it secure to use data from my session to use it as an query? Isn't it possible to get the userID from the DB instead?

Comment: You need something ( like the email address stored in your session ) to compare to the database entries in order to narrow your query results down to the one you want. If you don't want to use session variables directly in your model you can store the email address in a separate variable and pass it into the model like I did in the second example. Otherwise I don't know how you could retrieve a single record from the db without anything to compare it to.

Comment: I don't think this is any less secure than any other way. Another way would be to use the WHERE query with an argument supplied from the $this->input->post() variable directly from the login form. However if you went this route your users would have to log in over and again every time they tried to access their profile information, since the $_POST info would be gone after they successfully logged in.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I'll try to implement it now. If everything is going just fine, I'll accept your answer! Thanks for your help, time and info sheriff!

Comment: One more question before implementing it, which method of the 2 is prefered and why?

Comment: BTW. Do I still will be needing my foreach in my view? Basically I just have 1 record, so a loop isn't needed right?

Comment: Honestly, I am not 100% sure about this, but I started using the second method just to clean up code and not have to call session info directly in the model. I don't know if it actually hurts anything or not. :/

Comment: I usually always return info from the data model as $query->result_array(). Even if there is only one record, it usually stores all the info from the record in a 1-dimensional associative array, and then puts that in an indexed array. So, yes you will probably need to use foreach or alternatively use $data['records'] = $query[0]; ( in the controller ).  If you are not sure what format your data is stored in, I would recommend using var_dump($query); in the controller, followed by die; to view the data structure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33864/discussion-between-mxx-and-sheriff-mclawdog)

Comment: can you maybe come back to the chatroom?

Comment: I'm back in the chatroom